# Trying to stream direct to AWS.S3 .NET Core

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core, file-upload

- Context: I've been trying to find a "proper" solution to upload a file throw an API endpoint and upload the stream from request.Body without using the "IFormFile" so that I will have no data binding or load on the memory(if possible).
  I tried https://trailheadtechnology.com/dos-and-donts-for-streaming-file-uploads-to-azure-blob-storage-with-net-mvc/  and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming
  but I got stuck on issues like this "Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded" or MultipartReader with currentStream = 0.
  Next thing I want to try is to somehow get from request.Body the stream and only send the stream without boundary and those headers.
- My question is: What would be a better solution for streaming file upload to AWS.S3 of big files without having big load on memory?

Comment: Why azure-blob-storage tag?

Comment: @GauravMantri forgot about it. removed